# Custom navigation button but the text is not clear as the system

Tags: uibutton, uilabel, uibarbuttonitem

I use custom view to set a UIButton on the navigation bar.

But the text on the button like below:

[image]

is not like the default button text that clear.

[image]

I tried to add another label on the button, but it seems failed.

I also tied code like this, but seems also not working.

```
doneButton.titleLabel.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
doneButton.titleLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1.0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These code just works well.

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize]];
button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
button.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,-1);
button.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

I got it from https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes which is very great for custom UI fulfillment.